# How can i return a string after reversing it from a function in without using the C++ STL?

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I am trying to return a string from a function but the code doesn't seem to work. My assignment requires no use of C++ STL.

```
include<iostream>
using namespace std;
string reverse (string input){  
    string rev;
    for (int i=input.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        rev[i]=input[i];
    }
    return rev;
}


int main() {
    string input;
    cout<<"Enter the string:";
    cin>>input;

    string revInput = reverse(input);
    cout <<revInput;
}
```

Comment: You're returning the result fine. The problem is that your function doesn't actually reverse the string.

Comment: You need to put the last element of the input into element 0 of `rev`, 2nd-to-last in element 1, and so on.

Comment: `My assignment`. Not words we really want to hear here on Stack Overflow. Sure, it's a programming Q/A site. And sure, we could just *give* you the answer to your question. The problem with that, however, is that you will not learn anything by just being told. Perhaps these questions are best left in the hands of your tutor, who can guide you in the write direction as opposed to strangers on the internet that will tell you the answer, but not necessarily leave you with a worthwhile understanding. Unless, of course, `My assignment` is in regards to setting your vars. In which case, go ham! :)

Comment: `std::string` is part of the STL.

Comment: std::string, std::cin, and std::cout are not part of the STL, except as the neologism that treats those letters as an abbreviation for “STandard Library” rather than with their original meaning of “Standard Template Library”, which gave C++ iterators,, algorithms, containers, and function objects. – Pete Becker 39 mins ago

Answer (score 3):

You are not allocating any memory for the output string.  Your use of `operator[]` is out of bounds of the output string and thus is **undefined behavior**.

Also, your loop is iterating the input string backwards and filling the output string backwards, so the result is the same as the input, instead of the reverse of the input.

You need to either:

- pre-allocate the output string before entering the loop, and use a separate index for input and output strings:

  ```
  string reverse (string input){
      string rev;
      rev.resize(input.length()); // <-- add this
      for (int in = input.length()-1, out = 0; in >= 0; --in, ++out){
          rev[out] = input[in];
      }
      return rev;
  }
  ```
- Inside the loop, use the output string's `operator+=` instead of its `operator[]`:

  ```
  string reverse (string input){
      string rev;
      rev.reserve(input.length()); // <-- optional
      for (int i = input.length()-1; i >= 0; - - i){
          rev += input[i];
      }
      return rev;
  }
  ```

Comment: First one won't work as index value for both of the string is same. Second one works, Gracious.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  He wants to do it without using the STL.  Clearly, he should show some effort towards that end himself.

Comment: @SidS I'm not using the STL to reverse the string.

Comment: You're still using the STL.

Comment: @SidS Seriously? The assignment is clearly to implement reverse without using the reverse function from the STL. Not to avoid using std::string, std::cin or std::cout.